# Print catcodes as subscripts

Tags: expl3, catcodes

I have the following code to print catcodes as subscripts. Can one improve it to work also for the backslash and the braces? And what about the space? (I'm not asking about the comment char and ignored characters but it would be interesting too).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\showcatcodes { m }
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } 
   {
     \tl_to_str:n {##1} \textsubscript{\char_value_catcode:n{`##1}}
   }
 }  

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\showcatcodes{abcde123!$_ ^€\{\}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably this can be done by varying the output of `\tl_show_analysis:N`

Comment: Something like `\def\showcatcodes#1#2\relax{%
  \string#1%
  \ifcat ###1$_{6}$\else%
  \ifcat &#1$_{4}$\else%
  \ifcat A#1$_{11}$\else%
  \ifcat .#1$_{12}$\else%
  \ifcat $#1$_{3}$\else%
  \ifcat _#1$_{8}$\else%
  \ifcat ^#1$_{7}$\else%
  \ifcat \noexpand\relax\noexpand#1$_{0}$\else%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\showcatcodes#2\relax\fi%
}` will show `\{` and `\}` and other macros as catcode 0, but it does not handle actual braces `{` and `}`.   Note invocation as `\showcatcodes abc&de#123!$_ ^€\{\}\relax`

Comment: @JosephWright: I liked the "probably" -- it means that I didn't overlook something obvious ;-). I checked `\tl_show_analysis:N` but it returns things like `\abc` as a single token so I'm not sure if it is suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\showcatcodes { v }
 {
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { . } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   { \ulrike_value_catcode:x { \tl_to_str:n {##1} } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ulrike_value_catcode:n
 {
  #1\textsubscript{\char_value_catcode:n { `#1 }}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ulrike_value_catcode:n { x }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\showcatcodes{abcde123!$_ ^€\{\}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output with XeLaTeX (after removing `inputenc` and `fontenc`):

[image]

Final variant with `\textvisiblespace` and monospaced fonts for the characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\showcatcodes { v }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \ttfamily
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { . } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   { \ulrike_value_catcode:x { \tl_to_str:n {##1} } }
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ulrike_value_catcode:n
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { \textvisiblespace } { #1 }
  \textsubscript{\normalfont\char_value_catcode:n { `#1 }}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ulrike_value_catcode:n { x }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\showcatcodes{abcde123!$_ ^€\{\}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works fine. I added a test  `\tl_if_blank:nTF` to print the space as `\textvisiblespace`. But what does `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 } ` do? It is a rest from some older code?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it should have been removed.

Answer (score 10):

Apart from spaces you could do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\showcatcodes { m }
 {
   \expandafter\tl_map_inline:nn\expandafter{ \detokenize{#1} }
   {
     \tl_to_str:n {##1} \textsubscript{\char_value_catcode:n{`##1}}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\showcatcodes{a bcde123!$_ ^€\{\} {} } 
\end{document}
```

spaces you ought to be able to do by using `\scantokens` to change the catcode of space after making everything else safe with `\detokenize but scantokens is a dangerous beast and it's biting back at present.

Comment: That's good. But I think you should use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_inline:nn { on }` and `\tl_map_inline:on  { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }` ;-)

Comment: I was expecting egreg to reprimand me on poor l3 style not you:-)  I did actually try \tl_map_inline:on and ;xn but as they didn't exist I reverted to form and used \expandafter :-)

Comment: Actually I don't understand why it works. Isn't after \detokenize the argument a list of chars with catcode 12? So why are the subscripts "correct" ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are not looking up the catcodes of the tokens passed in, you are looking up the current catcode values. If you want to inspect the catcodes of the tokens then you need `\ifcat a #1 11 \else \ifcat^#1 7 \else....`

Comment: I'm not sure if we have a standard function in L3 to return the catcode of a token as a number...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that `l3tl-analysis` could be tweaked into doing it, but some trick by Bruno is needed.