# Active character can be defined, but not within \def?

Tags: active-characters

This is a follow up to my earlier question here: [Detect catcode of next character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697260/detect-catcode-of-next-character)

What I want to do: Count the number of `"` used in the document body. I am not using `"` for purposes such as math, babel shortcuts, or Unicode characters. Just dialog quotations (fiction writing, English).

I hunted around various packages, and see that `polyglossia` has `gloss-dutch`, which sets some accented characters to be active. This is done withing a `\def` macro. It looked like just what I need. To my surprise, it works when I write the code *not* within a `\def`, but fails when I write the code *within* a `\def` (inaccessible). MWE, which works as-is:

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile using lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec} % Less-minimal exaple would need this.
\defaultfontfeatures{} % Reset, to avoid tlig for this MWE.
\newcounter{dblq}
\def\shazam{} % Placeholder.

% To see the problem, uncomment/comment:

% Uncomment these 4 lines:
%\def\shazam{
%  \catcode`\"=13
%  \def "{”\stepcounter{dblq}}
%}

% And apply comment to these two lines:
\catcode`\"=13
\def "{”\stepcounter{dblq}}

\begin{document}
\shazam

"What in the world," he asked, "is happening here?"

\typeout{DBLQ=\arabic{dblq}}
\end{document}
```

Reason for `lualatex` is that I use only utf-8 with `fontspec`.

I have tried various random changes such as removing space, using `\let`, etc. No joy. Also fails with `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: that's expected and same as "you can not use verb in the argument of a command)  move the catcode setting before the def

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Alas, in the "real" usage (rather than MWE) the code sits within a hook (such as `\AtBeginDocument`) and the problem also arises there. But if I change the catcode outside the hook, it works. But I do not know if that would cause potential problems, with other items loaded at the hook.

Comment: no the catcode setting only affects the characters read from the file it has no effect at all on tokens so if you set it, add to the hook and set it back, it ony affects characters added on those lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setting `\catcode` affects the conversion of characters in the input to character tokens but it has no effect at all on character tokens.

In

```
\def\shazam{
  \catcode`\"=13
  \def "{”\stepcounter{dblq}}
}
```

the body of the command definition has been tokenized with a catcode 12 `"` so the `\catcode` setting does not affect this (but would affect following text) and `\def "` is a syntax error.

```
\catcode`\"=13
\def\shazam{
  \def "{”\stepcounter{dblq}}
}
```

defines the command with active `"` (even if `"` is not active at the point `\shazam` is used.

Comment: Thanks. I see that others found this useful, but my actual usage (not MWE) puts the catcode and shazam inside a hook, and there it causes problems. Will investigate more.

Comment: you need to have the catcode setting outside the hook setting (you may also want it inside the definition of `\shazam` to affect following characters. @rallg

Comment: Will invesitgate. My limited understanding of catcodes is that changing a catcode involves taking the cat to a veterinarian.

Comment: See my added answer, below yours. Possibly of general interest.

Answer (score 0):

After digesting what David wrote, and re-inspecting the code for parts of `babel` and `polyglossia`, I was still mystified. Their code defined active characters within a macro, but in a manner that did not work for me. Understand that for reasons unrelated to the
original question, I need to activate and define the character `\AtBeginDocument` or perhaps `\AfterEndPreamble` (etoolbox).

Then it dawned on me: The other code was loaded using `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage`. Maybe those macros did something magical? Yes! So here is something that works, and may be useful to others:

1. Create file `dblq.sty` containing this line:

```
\ProvidesFile{dblq.sty}[2023/10/01 v0.01 LaTeX file (double quotes).]
\catcode`\"=13
\def "{”\stepcounter{dblq}}
\AtEndDocument{
  \catcode`\"=12
  \typeout{You used \arabic{dblq}\string ".}
}
\endinput
```

Then put it next to the document, or command-line `mktexlsr` to find it.

2. In the document class (or Preamble}:

```
\newcounter{dblq}
\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{dblq}}
```

3. Here is another MWE that illustrates its usage. This assumes that file `dblq.sty` is already there:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{fontspec} % If building with lualatex.
\def\doesNotCount{"Hello World," they said.}
\newcounter{dblq}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\uni#1{No\obeyspaces} % This MWE only, pdflatex.
  % \def\uni#1{{\char"#1}\obeyspaces} % uncomment for lualatex
  \RequirePackage{dblq}
}
\begin{document}
\def\doesCount{"Hello Again," they said.}
\doesNotCount\par
\doesCount\par
"Hello to you, too," they replied.\par
"Deise is sch\"one," said Hans.\par
Finally, "\uni{2116} kidding!" they shouted.\par
\end{document}
```

That correctly counts 8 doublequote. The ones in `\doesNotCount` are not counted, because they are written prior to activation. The active character does not affect `\"o` and is not counted. Although `\uni` might not be necessary, I use it for my own purposes, so I wrote it here.

I do not use babel/polyglossia shortcuts, so I do not know if this interferes with them.

EDIT: Modified per suggestion in comment.

Comment: It would be much better to add `\catcode\`\"=13`              ... `\catcode\`\"=12`  to `dblq.sty` so that if used in the normal way via `\usepackage{dblq}` in the preamble it does not give low level errors.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for looking. I intend to use this technique for trapping usage of " when I should have used tlig or pasted Unicode characters. The goal is to reduce doublequotes to 0.